# How to override product attribute Save.php controller using modulein magento 2?

Tags: magento2, controllers, magento2.3.1, admin-controller

I am trying to create a module in which I am facing some issues to override Save.php Controller as well as save that data in the new table.
[image]

here is my updated di.xml code, but now after click on save, the redirect URL is blank.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save" type="Lucent\LiTab\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save" />
</config>
```

and my controller code for override is

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Lucent\LiTab\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute;

class Save extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        print_r($data);
        die();
    }
}
```

So please let me know where I did wrong code.

Please give me a solution for this!

Comment: Have u  check that `$this->getRequest()->getPostValue()` field is gives  your custom field value?

Comment: actually when I click on save attribute, not works. it means this code does not override.

Comment: @AmitBera I Updated code I get a response for that field but error to not redirect that attribute page some error comes.

Comment: is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

**di.xml** is incorrect. Please try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Catalog\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Save" />
</config>
```

Comment: thanks but not working

Comment: Is your module showing in the list after running the command:
php bin/magento module:status

Comment: thanks, yes, it is.

Comment: @Vishal I've fixed a typo for the for="" attribute